# How to select hierarchy collection? (mixed with non hierarchy data, etc)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

Having the table:

[image: table schema and data]

I need to show the following:

```
| ID | PERSONID | MASTERID | CHILDID     | VALUE | DEPTHLEVEL |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 3        |  78452   |  21456      |  100  |     1      |
| 2  | 3        |  21456   |             |  0    |     2      |
| 3  | 3        | 652314   | 417859      |  115  |     1      |
| 4  | 3        | 417859   |             |  0    |     2      |
| 5  | 4        | 998654   | 223655      |  300  |     1      |
| 6  | 4        | 223655   |             |  0    |     2      |
| 7  | 4        | 201302   |789654,441592|  200  |     1      |
| 8  | 4        | 789654   |             |  0    |     2      |
| 9  | 4        | 441592   |             |  0    |     2      |
| 10 | 5        | 999852   |             |  123  |     1      |
```

Look at the row with id 10 this row has not relations (childs), the row with id 7 has two childs.

I need to quit (put value to 0) the value for every child/leaf.

For the row 1-9 I try the following query:

```
select v.* from
(
  select v.id, v.personid,
    case when level > 1
      then 0
    else
      v.value
    end thevalue,
    v.masterid, v.childid, level depthlevel
    from tmpsimpleexample v
    start with v.childid is not null
    connect by v.masterid = prior v.childid
) v
order by v.id
```

Results:
[image: Results from my query]

Look the rows with id 7, 8 is the master with two childs, *I need to put this in one row*.

**This is the first problem.**

Also I need to show the data with no hierarchy relation(id 10 in expected result table, id 11 in image table data).

I think that I can query all rows with masterid not referenced by a childid and then make an union between the first query(above) and the query to search all master id not referenced by childid.

The query to to search all rows with masterid not referenced by childid will show me the row without relation and the master rows of level 1.

```
select id, personid, value thevalue, masterid, childid, 1 depthlevel
    from TMPSIMPLEEXAMPLE
    where masterid not in
      (select childid from TMPSIMPLEEXAMPLE where childid is not null)
```

[image: Querying all rows with masterid not referenced by chilid]

Here I can do an union and the result will fit my requirements(except the childid concatenate for master row).

```
select v.* from
(
  select v.id, v.personid,
    case when level > 1
      then 0
    else
      v.value
    end thevalue,
    v.masterid, v.childid, level depthlevel
    from tmpsimpleexample v
    start with v.childid is not null
    connect by v.masterid = prior v.childid
  union
  select id, personid, value thevalue, masterid, childid, 1 depthlevel
    from TMPSIMPLEEXAMPLE
    where masterid not in
      (select childid from TMPSIMPLEEXAMPLE where childid is not null)
) v
order by v.id
```

Almost final result:

[image: Almost the final result]

But knowing that my real table has hundred of thousands of records **make union like that are a good approach?**

Comment: You should be able to solve this with analytic functions, could you provide the raw data for your sample so that I can see exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a stab at what I *think* your source data looks like:

```
| ID | PERSONID | MASTERID  | CHILDID | VALUE |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  |        3 |    78452  | 21456   | 100   |
| 2  |        3 |    21456  |         |  -1   |
| 3  |        3 |    652314 | 417859  | 115   |
| 4  |        3 |    417859 |         |  -1   |
| 5  |        4 |    998654 | 223655  | 300   |
| 6  |        4 |    223655 |         |  -1   |
| 7  |        4 |    201302 | 441592  | 200   |
| 7  |        4 |    201302 | 789654  | 200   |
| 9  |        4 |    441592 |         |  -1   |
| 8  |        4 |    789654 |         |  -1   |
| 10 |        4 |    999852 |         | 123   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

The following query gets you your desired results:

```
enter code here
select id, 
       personid, 
       masterid,
       listagg(childid, ',') within group (order by childid) childid, 
       -- Took a guess that all values for a personid were the same and didn't need to be aggregated...
       min(decode(depthlevel, 1, value, null)) value,
       min(depthlevel) depthlevel
from  (select v.*, level depthlevel
       from   tmpsimpleexample v
       connect by v.masterid = prior v.childid
       -- Trick here is to start with all of the desired starting conditions...
       start with not exists ( select 'X' from tmpsimpleexample v2 where v2.childid = v.masterid ))
group by id, personid, masterid;
```

If ordering of your *CHILDID* is important, you would need to re-join the nested view with *TMPSIMPLEEXAMPLE*:

```
select v1.id, 
       v1.personid, 
       v1.masterid,
       listagg(v1.childid, ',') within group (order by v2.id) childid, 
       min(decode(depthlevel, 1, v1.value, null)) value,
       min(depthlevel) depthlevel
from  (select v.*, level depthlevel
       from   tmpsimpleexample v
       connect by v.masterid = prior v.childid
       start with not exists ( select 'X' from tmpsimpleexample v2 where v2.childid = v.masterid )) v1,
       tmpsimpleexample v2
-- Outer Join is important!
where  v1.childid = v2.masterid (+)
group by v1.id, v1.personid, v1.masterid;
```

The real magic here is the LISTAGGG function.  If you are not on 11g or better yet (why not?!?), then the following article can guide you in building your own aggregate function:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php